# Are the Fourier coefficients of smooth functions on torus absolutely summable?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, fourier-analysis

Suppose $T: L^p(\mathbb{T}^n) \to L^q(\mathbb{T}^n)$ is linear and bounded, and for each $m\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $T(e^{2m\pi ix}) = a_m e^{2m\pi ix}$, where $\{a_m\}_{m\in \mathbb{Z}^n}$ is bounded. How does this imply the following?
\begin{equation}
Tf(x) = \sum_m a_m \hat f(m) e^{2m\pi ix}, ~\text{for every}~ f\in C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n).
\end{equation}

I know the above equation holds for trigonometric polynomials. I tried to use the density argument to extend to all $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ functions. But I need that the Fourier coefficients of $f$ are absolutely summable. Is this true that the Fourier coefficients of a $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ function are absolutely summable? If not, does the Fourier series of a $C^\infty(\mathbb{T}^n)$ function always converge to itself? And what is the right way to complete this density argument?

Comment: $c_n(\partial_{x_k} f) = 2i \pi m_k c_n(f)$

Comment: Hi, do you mean consider the differential operator $\partial_{x_k}$? But it doesn't satisfy $a_m$ are bounded.

Comment: Integrate by parts $c_n(h)=\int_0^1 h(x)e^{-2i\pi n x}dx$ to get that when $h\in C^\infty(\Bbb{R/Z})$ then $c_n(h) = o(n^{-r})$ for all $r$.

Comment: Thank you! My understanding of your comment is that the Fourier coefficients of a smooth function on torus must have rapid decay (decay faster than any polynomials). That's a helpful remark to me! Is there a way to obtain that there exists $r$ and $C$, such that for all $n$, $c_n(h) \leq C n^{-r}$? I think I need some uniformity in $n$ to get convergence of the series.

Comment: Integrate by parts $r$ times, $|\int_0^1 h^{(r)}(x)e^{-2i\pi n x}dx|\le \|h^{(r)}\|_\infty$. It works the same way in dimension $\ge 2$.

Comment: I think I misunderstood your previous comment. By $o(n^{-r})$, do you mean that for every $r$, there exists a common constant $C$, such that for all $n$, $c_n(h) \leq C n^{-r}$? And in that way the absolute summability follows. Correct?

Answer (score 1):

I summarize reuns' comments here. By smoothness of $f$, van der Corput's lemma implies that for every $k$, there exists a constant $C_k>0$, such that for all $m\in \mathbb{Z}^n$, $|\hat f(m)| \leq C_k m^{-k}$. Note $\widehat f(m)$ are also bounded. Then by taking $k>n$, we obtain the absolute summability.